# AutoLayout transform CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, autolayout

I have an `UIView` with a frame size that is dependent on AutoLayout constraints.

In that size changing view, there is a full-size (background) `CALayer`.
When The device rotate, I want the background layer's frame to **animate** with the parent view when it rotates.
The problem is that the `size` that is passed from the `viewWillTransitionToSize` is of the view **before** the AutoLayout constraints are applied.

How should I handle the background layer resizing animation to work properly?

In this code sample the `self.background` is the layer attached to the nested view:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({context in
        self.background.bounds.size = size
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Thank you.

---

**Solution:**

I have implemented the class function `layerClass` in the view that returns the custom `CALayer` - so the AutoLayot is handled by the system.

Because the layer is dynamic and responds to events I used Notification Center to deliver the events to the layers.

Comment: You might have to implement `layoutSubviews` on the view so that you work alongside auto layout (which also does its work there). Let me know when you get this one figured out. The lack of auto layout for layers is a _huge_ problem. You might want to switch to a UIView instead of a CALayer just so you can deal with this issue.

Comment: Added my solution... @matt

Comment: Right, that was basically what I said - the layer becomes the main layer _of a view_, and so autolayout applies.